# Code printing entire string on each line?

Tags: java

I am trying to write code that will take a given word (in this case "Alphabet") and print it backwards.
With my current method, I manage to get it to print backwards, however, instead of printing on character per line, it is printing the entire word, starting with the last character on the first print line and then adding the following character on the next.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        String backwards = "Alphabet";
        for (int i = backwards.length(); i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(backwards.substring(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `for` loop to start at `length() - 1` and use `String.charAt(int)` instead of `String.substring(int)`. Like,

```
for (int i = backwards.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(backwards.charAt(i));
}
```

Will change your output to

```
t
e
b
a
h
p
l
A
```

surrounded by a bunch of empty lines (which I assume you want).

Comment: Thanks a ton! I've been struggling with this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, you can do something like this too (in one line):

```
String s = "Alphabet";
new StringBuilder(s).reverse().chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).forEach(System.out::println);
```

If, of course, you are in Java 8+.

Answer (score 0):

If you want yo use the method `substring()` you can do it as below:

```
for (int i = backwards.length(); i > 0; i--) {
      System.out.println(backwards.substring(i-1, i));
}
```

If you want to know how this method works take a look here: [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)).